# General formula for n-Simplex root?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inverse-function, simplex

Given a number $k$, is it possible to find which term in the $n$-Simplex sequence it corresponds to? I've only been able to find formulae for the triangular root.

Examples:

For $k = 10$ in the triangular (2-Simplex) number sequence, the triangular root would be 4, since the fourth triangular number is 10.

For $k = 210$ in the polytope (4-Simplex) number sequence, the pentatonic root would be 7, since the seventh pentatope number is 210.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this in general, you would have to find the inverse function of the map
$$
n \mapsto \binom{n+k-1}{k}
$$
for fixed $k$. For small $k$, you got a nice little polynomial, and you may succeed. For large $k$, if you succeed, you've done better than these guys:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143332/is-there-an-asymptotic-formula-for-an-inverse-function-of-the-binomial-coefficie